# Automatically including object files using Boost.build

Tags: c++, bjam, boost-build

I'm using the latest version of boost-build found in boost 1.46.  Given `main.cpp` which depends on `a.h` and `b.h`, using the boost-build's ability to auto-detect dependencies my jam file is simply

```
exe my_prog : main.cpp ;
```

But, if there is an implementation file, `b.cpp`, the object `b.o` is not produced nor linked in.  I'd like my build scripts to be minimal, and not require tweaking everytime I add a new file.  So, how can I do this automatically?

Edited to reflect true intent vs. what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason this won't work?

```
exe my_prog : main.cpp b.cpp ;
```

Doing it the way you want sounds painful and unpleasant, especially for someone new to boost-build.  Plus there may be times when you only need the header, and not the cpp.

If your code is impeccably organized, and you only need the files in the current directory, you can get all the cpp files easily enough:

```
exe my_prog : [ glob *.cpp ] ;
```

(There are other arguments to glob that will allow you to filter out backup/recovery files your editor may create.  And there are other versions of glob that descend into child directories.)

If you have multiple cpp files needed by multiple final executables, you will be better off making a library with the `lib` rule and using that as one of the sources for your executable.

```
lib blib : b.cpp ;
exe my_prog : main.cpp blib ;
```

Comment: +1, I didn't even think to do that. I'm unit testing my code the hard way: multiple executables, each testing a module or two, so consolidating the programs objects into a static lib is just the thing. I'm going to leave the question open, as I'd like to understand how to update dependencies on the fly, but thank you.

Comment: If you're doing testing, you should look into Boost-Build's [testing rules][http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/bbv2/builtins/testing.html].  Not only will they compile, but they'll also run your test application.

Comment: I know. I literally just changed over the code base to use boost-build as my make scripts were brittle and failed at propagating options correctly, so all my tests are just one off programs that I run and verify the output of by hand (mostly - I used Mathematica's `Scan` function to generate all permutations of the input for a math library).  It will take awhile to set up them up using boost-build, and I'm up against a deadline.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the fact that your solution solves the problem without having to dig into the internals of boost-build. Hence, you get the check-mark.